# Dotnet 'new' command not working with Framework 4.5?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-4.5

I'm trying to create a 4.5 framework Class Library project with dotnet `new` command as following:

```
dotnet new classlib -lang C# -f net45 -o TestProject
```

> Error: Invalid Parameters:
> -f net45
> "net45" is not a valid value for -f (Framework).

[As seen in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/core/tools/dotnet-new#classlib), it seems that .Net Framework is not supported:

> -f Values: netcoreapp  to create a .NET Core class library or
> netstandard  to create a .NET Standard class library. The
> default is netstandard2.0.

Any idea on how to create a .Net Framework Class Library project via command line?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new#classlib) specify only .NET 5, .NET Core and .NET Standard.

Comment: `dotnet new classlib --help` show you supported framework by the command.

Comment: You can create [you own template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-project-template). Maybe a template to generate a .NET Framework library already exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use dotnet new to create an ASP.NET Web Application Empty .Net Framework 4.7.2 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649749/is-it-possible-to-use-dotnet-new-to-create-an-asp-net-web-application-empty-net)

Answer (score 0):

To create a .NET Framework Class Library project targeting version 4.5, you can simply use the dotnet new classlib command and then manually update the target framework in the project file.

Step 1 :- Create the Class Library project:

```
dotnet new classlib -lang C# -o TestProject
```

Step 2 :- Navigate to the TestProject directory:
Step 3 :- Open the TestProject.csproj file in a text editor.

Find the  element and change it to net45.

Your TestProject.csproj file should look something like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net45</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```