# Is it possible to use dotnet new to create an ASP.NET Web Application Empty .Net Framework 4.7.2 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've been trying to find a way to create a ASP.NET Web Application with .Net Framework v4.7.2 using dotnet new. But so far I couldn't find anything.

I checked dotnet new -l and it isn't on the list. So I tried several things.

Using:

`dotnet new web --framework net472 -n ProjectName`

It doesn't work and gives:

```
Error: Invalid parameter(s):
--framework net472
    'net472' is not a valid value for --framework (Framework).
```

Used:

`dotnet new web --target-framework-override net472 -n ProjectName`

It just goes to default and creates a ASP.NET Core project.

Is it actually possible?

Comment: dotnet is really centered around .NET Core. Not .NET Framework. Anyways - why create a new ASP.NET/.NET Framework app in 2021?

Comment: Exactly duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858648/dotnet-new-command-not-working-with-framework-4-5 Read the comments and hints are enough.

Comment: @mason why use .net framework? Because there are platforms that are still based on it, unfortunately. It is what it is, so I was wondering if there was a way.

Comment: Yes, there are still platforms based on it. I help maintain a number of .NET Framework apps in my day job. But that still doesn't explain why you would create a *new* one in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

The dotnet tool does not include a built in template for creating a new .NET Framework empty web application.

However, you can create your own templates compatible with the dotnet tool. I won't explain that how here as I've never done it, but a web search reveals documentation and blog articles about how to create your own.

I assume using dotnet isn't really necessary, you just want a quick and easy way to create a new .NET Framework ASP.NET Empty web app. You could use Visual Studio to create a new empty web app and then source control it, and when you want to make a new site you just clone the site and go from there. Or pick any other templating tool out there, such as [T4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit).